# How can I inline an empty div and table

Tags: css

How can I inline this empty div and make the table display inline?

This table is generated by an ASP.NET radio list.

```
<div class="aClass">a</div>
<table id="ctl00_">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ctl00_0" type="radio" name="a" value="0">
                <label for="ctl00_0">a</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="ctl00_1" type="radio" name="b" value="1">
                <label for="ctl00_1">a</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Css

```
.aClass {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59xpp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that table is the immediate next sibling of that div,  you can try [adjacent siblings selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

`+` is an adjacent siblings selector.

```
.aClass {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align:middle; /* Add this */
}
.aClass + table{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; /* Add this */
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59xpp/1/)

Comment: +1, thank you, but what if I don't want to make any changes to label class :(

Comment: @CustomizedName Do you mean div having `.aClass`?

Comment: adding "display: inline-block;" is enough by the way :), thank